# Will every continuous map from $S^1$ to itself have a fixed point?

Tags: continuity

Will every continuous map from  $S^1$ to itself have a fixed point? I cant understand how to conclude anything from this

Comment: No. Consider a rotation.

Comment: Can u please explain in detail

Comment: @learnmore: Rotate the circle through a right angle around its centre. Is that a continuous map? Does it have a fixed point?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on what's been said in the comments: consider the unit circle with polar coordinates; $\mathbb{S}^1 = \{ (1, \theta) : \theta \in [0,2 \pi) \}$. Then the map

$f(1,\theta) = (1, \theta + \frac{\pi}{2} \hspace{0.3cm} \text{mod} \hspace{0.3cm} 2 \pi)$

is a rotation. It's continuous but doesn't have a fixed point.